# Is it possible to format the code as it makes Chrome Developer Tools in the tab "Elemets"?

Tags: html, formatting, google-chrome-devtools

Example:
BEFORE        ->          AFTER
http://goo.gl/RHbvOi -> http://goo.gl/oLu9Eh

Comment: Your question is quite paradoxal... If you see it working in chrome, obviously it is possible to do it. I think you may want to rephrase the question, but first try to achieve something by yourself in order to show us some code cause that's how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Control K + Control D formats code in visual studio, not sure what you are using though